# Eliminar y reemplazar valores en pandas python usando condicionales

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo el siguiente Dataframe

```
prueba = 

     M1    M2    M3    M4
0     1     1     1   NaN
1     2     3     3   NaN
2     3     2     2     1
3     4   NaN     1   NaN
4     1   NaN   NaN   NaN
5     1     3     2     2
6     3     3   NaN     1
7     2     2     3   NaN
8     1     3   NaN     1
9     6     4     5     5
```

Requiero hacer dos tareas por cada una de las filas:

1. Si una columna esta vacia (NaN) y alguna siguiente tiene valor, que ese valor quede en la primera columna vacia y en las demás quede NaN...Es decir desplazar los valores hacia la izquierda
2. Si dos valores son iguales en una fila que lo deje solo en la primera columna que aparece: por ejemplo si M1 y M2 son iguales, que solo quede el valor en M1 y M2 se convierta en NaN, si el valor se repite en varios M debe quedar solo en el primero y en los otros NaN.

He intentado con las siguientes opciones:

Para la primera pregunta intente hacer una comparación por pares. Por ejemplo para M2 y M3:

`for row in prueba.itertuples():
    prueba['M2']= prueba.where((prueba['M2'].isnull() & prueba['M3'].notnull()), prueba['M3'])` pero genera error.

Para la segunda pregunta (Esta parte funciona)

```
prueba.loc[prueba['M1']== prueba['M2'] , 'M2'] = 'NaN'
prueba.loc[prueba['M1']== prueba['M3'] , 'M3'] = 'NaN'
prueba.loc[prueba['M1']== prueba['M4'] , 'M4'] = 'NaN'
prueba.loc[prueba['M2']== prueba['M3'] , 'M3'] = 'NaN'
prueba.loc[prueba['M2']== prueba['M4'] , 'M4'] = 'NaN'
prueba.loc[prueba['M3']== prueba['M4'] , 'M4'] = 'NaN'
```

Soy nueva programando, agradezco si me pueden ayudar para solucionar las dos preguntas mencionadas. Es importante el tiempo que se gaste encontrando la solución porque son muchos datos.

El Dataframe procesado debería salir así:

```
     M1     M2      M3    M4
0     1     NaN     NaN   NaN
1     2     3       NaN   NaN
2     3     2       1     NaN
3     4     1       NaN   NaN
4     1     NaN     NaN   NaN
5     1     3       2     NaN
6     3     1       NaN   NaN
7     2     3       NaN   NaN
8     1     3       NaN   NaN
9     6     4       5     NaN
```

Comment: No acabo de entender exactamente qué necesitas hacer en el paso 1. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo habría de quedar tu dataframe una vez procesado?

Comment: Hola Carolina bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Para cumplir la primera condición `1   NaN   3     4` debería quedar en `1    3    4    NaN` ? Es decir, simplemente desplazar los valores a la izquierda para eliminar todos los valores nulos entre los datos.

Comment: Si señor eso es lo que necesito hacer en la primera parte: desplazar los valores si es `1 NaN 3 4` debe quedar  `1 3 4 NaN`

Comment: Ya inclui el dataframe procesado.. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el segundo punto se puede usar de forma general `pandas.Series.drop_duplicates` pasando el argumento `keep="first"` para mantener solo la primera aparición. Una máscara boleana con `pandas.Series.duplicated` también funcionaría.

Para el primer punto no se me ocurre una forma vectorizada. Es posible hacerlo mediante el uso `pandas.DataFrame.apply` aplicado sobre las filas (`axis=1`) y que llame por cada fila a una función Python que use el método `pandas.Series.dropna` para construir la nueva fila.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = io.StringIO('''\
M1,M2,M3,M4
1,1,1,NaN
2,3,3,NaN
3,2,2,1
4,NaN,1,NaN
1,NaN,NaN,NaN
1,3,2,2
3,3,NaN,1
2,2,3,NaN
3,3,NaN,1
6,4,5,5
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, dtype="f")
```

Con lo anterior obtenemos un DataFrame que nos permite reproducir tu ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> df
>
>     M1   M2   M3   M4
> 0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
> 1  2.0  3.0  3.0  NaN
> 2  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
> 3  4.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
> 4  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
> 5  1.0  3.0  2.0  2.0
> 6  3.0  3.0  NaN  1.0
> 7  2.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
> 8  3.0  3.0  NaN  1.0
> 9  6.0  4.0  5.0  5.0
> ```

Ahora vamos a aplicar la idea explicada antes:

```
res = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
                                        .dropna()
                                        .values
                                     ),
                axis=1
              )
```

Con esto obtenemos algo que se acerca bastante:

> ```
> >>> res
>
>      0    1    2
> 0  1.0  NaN  NaN
> 1  2.0  3.0  NaN
> 2  3.0  2.0  1.0
> 3  4.0  1.0  NaN
> 4  1.0  NaN  NaN
> 5  1.0  3.0  2.0
> 6  3.0  1.0  NaN
> 7  2.0  3.0  NaN
> 8  3.0  1.0  NaN
> 9  6.0  4.0  5.0
> ```

Solo necesitamos agregar las columnas faltantes (columnas con todos los valores NaN) y renombrar el resto:

```
p_cols, m_cols = df.columns[:res.shape[1]], df.columns[res.shape[1]:] 
res.columns = p_cols

for col in m_cols:
    res[col] = np.nan
```

Resultado:

> ```
> >>> res
>
>     M1   M2   M3  M4
> 0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
> 1  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
> 2  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
> 3  4.0  1.0  NaN NaN
> 4  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
> 5  1.0  3.0  2.0 NaN
> 6  3.0  1.0  NaN NaN
> 7  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
> 8  3.0  1.0  NaN NaN
> 9  6.0  4.0  5.0 NaN
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entendí correctamente, pero según creo se trata de:

- En cada una de las filas del dataframe:

  1. Eliminar duplicados y quedarse sólo con una instancia de cada número que aparezca
  2. Rellenar el resto de la fila con NaN

Aunque este enunciado no coincide con el que tú has puesto, creo que al final el resultado es el mismo, y expresado de este modo queda más claro.

De hecho, esto sugiere otra forma de calcular ese resultado sin utilizar Pandas, sino extrayendo el array bidimensional subyacente al dataframe. En ese array se trata de recorrerlo por filas y construir con cada una un conjunto con sus elementos (los conjuntos eliminan automáticamente los duplicados). Tras esta transformación habrá filas con sólo dos elementos, otras con cuatro, etc.

Finalmente se puede construir un nuevo dataframe con todos esos conjuntos. Ya que Pandas al convertirlo a dataframe hará que todas las filas tengan la misma longitud, rellenará con NaN los elementos faltantes.

El problema de la idea anterior es que *los conjuntos no tienen un orden interno*, por tanto la primera fila, por ejemplo, daría lugar  a un conjunto con los elementos `1, NaN`, o quizás con los elementos `NaN, 1`. Es decir, no se preserva el orden en que los elementos se hayan añadido al conjunto, y esto no nos conviene porque queremos respetar ese orden cuando sean expandidos de nuevo en filas.

Una solución a esto consiste en el siguiente truco. En lugar de un conjunto, usamos un `OrderdeDict()`, que es un diccionario que preserva el orden en que se le añaden las claves. Usamos los elementos de cada fila para crear las claves de ese diccionario (los valores son irrelevantes y usaré `True`). Una clave repetida se almacena en la misma clave que hubiera. Si al final tomamos las claves del diccionario resultante (`.keys()`), tendremos el conjunto ordenado de los números de esa fila, en el orden en que fueron insertados, que es el orden de columnas de izquierda a derecha.

Es decir, yendo al grano, esta es mi idea:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

datos = """\
     M1    M2    M3    M4
0     1     1     1   NaN
1     2     3     3   NaN
2     3     2     2     1
3     4   NaN     1   NaN
4     1   NaN   NaN   NaN
5     1     3     2     2
6     3     3   NaN     1
7     2     2     3   NaN
8     1     3   NaN     1
9     6     4     5     5"""

# Leer el dataframe en cuestión
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(datos), sep=r'\s+')

# Construir la lista de las nuevas filas
r = []
for fila in df.values:
  r.append(OrderedDict({k:True for k in fila}).keys())

# Convertir a dataframe de nuevo la lista obtenida
resultado = df.DataFrame(r, columns=df.columns)
```

Resultado:

```
    M1   M2   M3  M4
0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
1  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
2  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
3  4.0  NaN  1.0 NaN
4  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
5  1.0  3.0  2.0 NaN
6  3.0  NaN  1.0 NaN
7  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
8  1.0  3.0  NaN NaN
9  6.0  4.0  5.0 NaN
```

**Actualización**

@Carolina me señala en un comentario que la fila 3 no cumple las especificaciones. Efectivamente en ella no están todos los NaN juntos a la derecha.

El error proviene de que el bucle que va metiendo cada elemento en un diccionario ordenado, mete también los `NaN`. En realidad sólo queremos preservar el orden original de los números, no de los `NaN`. Por tanto basta con no meter esos `NaN` en el diccionario, es decir:

```
r = []
for fila in df.values:
  r.append(OrderedDict({k:True for k in fila if not np.isnan(k)}).keys())
```

El problema es que ahora la lista `r` contendrá las filas resultantes sin ningún `NaN`, por lo que al crear a partir de ellas un DataFrame, el número de columnas final puede ser menor que el que teníamos originalmente si, por ejemplo (y como es el caso) a la derecha quedaban columnas en las que sólo había NaN.

Para arreglar este segundo problema, usaré el siguiente truco. Primero creo un dataframe con los datos que tengo en `r`. Este dataframe en general tendrá N columnas siendo N<=4. Seguidamente pongo nombre a esas columnas copiando los nombres del dataframe original, pero sólo los N primeros nombres. Finalmente utilizo `reindex()` en las columnas para expandir el número de columnas a las que tenía originalmente el dataframe. Esto rellenará con NaN las columnas extra que tenga que añadir. Es decir:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(r)
result.columns = df.columns[:result.shape[1]]
# En realidad, si te vale con que el dataframe resultante tenga sólo
# las columnas M1, M2, y M3 (ya que M4 sería todo NaN), podriamos dejarlo
# así. Si quieres que el resultado tenga el mismo número de columnas, entonces...

result = result.reindex(columns=df.columns)
print(result)
```

Y ahora sí:

```
    M1   M2   M3  M4
0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
1  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
2  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
3  4.0  1.0  NaN NaN
4  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
5  1.0  3.0  2.0 NaN
6  3.0  1.0  NaN NaN
7  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
8  1.0  3.0  NaN NaN
9  6.0  4.0  5.0 NaN
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta! El problema es que no me puede quedar un NaN entre valores: por ejemplo en la línea 3 debería quedar `4.0 1.0 NaN NaN`

Comment: @Carolina Tienes razón. He actualizado la respuesta para corregir ese problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias!